# PHP financial class, using XIRR function

Tags: php

I'm using [this financial class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/892-PHP-Financial-functions-with-the-Excel-function-names-.html) for calculating XIRR value of cash flows. But there is a problem, that occurs when the calculated value should be less than -57,60%. Instead of lets say -60% it returns something like -1.571.465.320.791.475.063.612.392.992.979.424.882.196.480,00%

Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Does the php financial class XIRR function have an argument for GUESS. As it seems for the default guess rate of 10%, the differential is very close to zero thus you are getting garbage results. The error may be attributed to faulty implementation of the algorithm being used by the php financial class library

As you only have 2 cash flows, thus I was able to confirm that there is only one rate of return of -57.65% as shown below

```
-4000 + 3506/(1+i)^0.153425 = 0
3506/(1+i)^0.153425 = 4000 
1/(1+i)^0.153425 = 4000/3506
(1+i)^0.153425 = 3506/4000
1+i = (0.8765)^(1/0.153425)
i = (0.8765)^(1/0.153425) - 1
i = (0.8765)^(6.5178426) - 1
i = 0.4235 - 1
i = -0.5765
i = -57.65%
```

The online version of MS Excel is reporting a 0% rate with its XIRR function yet this online XIRR calculator reports -57.65% as the rate using a guess rate of -50%. At the default guess rate of 10% , the online [XIRR calculator](http://finance.thinkanddone.com/online-xirr-calculator.html) reports NAN thus having me thinking that XIRR algorithm comes to a situation where there is a negative number for which it attempts to calculate a root

Answer (score 0):

You might want to post your example inputs to the function, so others can try to reproduce it. XIRR is an 'approximate' function. It starts with a guess at the correct value and then tries to refine that guess. Sometimes, it cannot come to a correct answer and I'm guessing that's what is happening here. I'd also try to put your values into Excel or OpenOffice and see what result you get.

See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837759.aspx) for some background information.

Comment: An example, that returns wrong number:
`print $test = $f->XIRR(array(-4000,3506), array(
     mktime(0,0,0,'03','16','2012'),
     mktime(0,0,0,'05','11','2012')
     ));`

I did try to put this numbers into excel, and it's working as it should.